# Passed data to new Activity is null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with passing data to a new activity. The passed data is not `null` but it does not contain any data when .getExtras() is called from the new activity. When I debug, the data is null at the new activity. Here is my implementation-

FirstActivity.java

```
Cursor cursor = databaseAccess.getData("SELECT * FROM TYPE");
    imageList.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(2);

        imageList.add(new Food(id, name, image));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //button to click to next page
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            Food labels = imageList.get(position);
            String no = labels.getId();
            Intent passIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtra("keyid", no);//pass id to next activity
            startActivity(passIntent);

        }
    });
```

SecondActivity.java

```
//declaration for gridview and implement adapter
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CustomGridAdapter1(this, R.layout.second_list, imageList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowId = data.getString("keyid");
    cursor = databaseAccess.getImage(rowId);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(2);

        imageList.add(new Recipe(id, name, image));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

databaseAcces.java

```
//display name and image in gridview at General.this
public Cursor getImage(String id) {
    Cursor cursor;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT RECIPE.id, RECIPE.name, RECIPE.image FROM RECIPE INNER JOIN TYPE WHERE RECIPE.type_id=TYPE.id AND RECIPE.type_id=\"" + id + "\" ";
    database = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened cause you put your data in extra directly but in receive you want get it with bundle!

replace

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
rowId = data.getString("keyid");
```

with

```
 rowId = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyid");
```

Answer (score 0):

**erfan's answer** is also correct but it is **not a very good practice** to pass just the key and data to other activities, **use `Bundle` instead.**

The main purpose of `Bundle` is to pass data between activities. The values that are to be passed are mapped to String keys which are later used in the next activity to retrieve the values.

In [*Sending data between activities* section of Android Developer site says:](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdba)

> We recommend that you use the Bundle class to set primitives known to
>   the OS on Intent objects. The Bundle class is highly optimized for
>   marshalling and unmarshalling using parcels.

To solve this issue, use `Bundle` to put data from calling activity and also use `Bundle` to get from the called activity.

So **replace**

```
String no = labels.getId();
Intent passIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
passIntent.putExtra("keyid", no);//pass id to next activity
```

**with**

```
String no = labels.getId();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("keyid", no);
Intent passIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
passIntent.putExtras(bundle);//pass id to next activity
```

and keep the second activity as it is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195427/discussion-on-answer-by-futurejj-passed-data-to-new-activity-is-null).

Comment: Replace putExtra() with putExtras()

Comment: Did this fix the issue?